# How to transfer IVectorView<InkStroke> in C++/CX

Tags: c++, uwp, casting, c++-cx

scenario: I would like to exchange InkStroke between devices running on the same LAN.

**Step1: collect all the strokes drawn on the screen from the client:**

```
// Send strokes to a remote server.
strokesToReplay = inkCanvas->InkPresenter->StrokeContainer->GetStrokes();
const int sz = sizeof(strokesToReplay);
char msgToSend[sz];
memcpy(msgToSend, &strokesToReplay, sz);
send(tcpClient.sockfd, msgToSend, sz, 0);
```

**Step2： receive data from the server part:**

```
// tcpServer is an instance of TCPServer, which contains
// a function that calls listen -> accept
// to establish a connection with the client
bytesRecv = tcpServer.recvFromClient();
// Received data was storaged in TCPServer::buffer (char buffer[16384])
```

What I would like to do is cast the data in the buffer into IVectorView.
So that it is possible to iterate InkStroke from it like:

```
for (InkStroke^ inkStroke : buffer) {
    ... to do
}
```

But here is the question: how can I cast char * to IVectorView?

I've tried memcpy() and static_cast.
But since there is no proper memory allocated in IVectorView, memcpy() will destroy the whole program.

static_cast() won't work with IVectorView.

Now I am thinking about copying the data into the clipboard, then calling the API provided by Microsoft that gets data from the clipboard and cast it into strokes automatically.
But I Do Not Know If This Works Or Not...
Is there any advice that you guys can give me?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm *very* sure that `const int sz = sizeof(strokesToReplay);` is already wrong. `GetStrokes` returns a dynamic list using `sizeof` on that will give a completely different result. And the `memcpy` also cannot be correct, you want to copy and send the actual strokes

Comment: You also can't just dump the memory of the strokes into a byte array, you need proper serialization and deserialization code

Comment: Sure thing, I've also considered that... Is there any advice that you can give me?

Comment: I've also thought about saving the strokes into a .gif file and sending it. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Storing it into an image format and then analyzing that seems extremely inefficient (you'd be transferring a lot of empty data each time you send it through the network). Just serializing the individual strokes has to be simpler

Comment: Good idea. I'm on it.

Comment: It seems like that we cannot initialize an empty InkStroke instance: **auto inkstroke = ref new Windows::UI::Input::Inking::InkStroke();** <- this is a private constructor. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's `InkStrokeBuilder` that creates `InkStroke`objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokebuilder?view=winrt-22000

Comment: **InkStrokeBuilder::CreateStroke()** needs  a list of points as a parameter. Any other way?

Comment: Put the strokes in an InkStrokeContainer (if they aren't in one already) and use InkStrokeContainer.SaveAsync. then send the resulting stream to the other process and use InkStrokeContainer.LoadAsync to recreate them on the other side.